# How to make Ansible use password if key was rejected?

Tags: ssh, authentication, ansible

My new server instances are configured to login on root via ssh with password. I want my Ansible playbook to reconfigure it to use keys instead and disable root login with password on first run, so I need something like this:

- **try to login with key**
- **if can't login with key:**

  - **login with password**
  - add key to authorized_keys
  - disable root login with password
  - optionally reconnect using key
- do other tasks

How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT**: To be clear, I'm not asking how to add key or disable root, that's just for context. I'm asking how to fallback to password if it couldn't authenticate with key. With `--ask-pass` or `ansible_ssh_pass` set, Ansible won't even try to use public key authentication

Comment: Good question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I took the ssh configuration to a separate playbook and I run it with -k option, then I run the main playbook without -k (using key from agent). I was hoping it can be wrapped in a single playbook though...

Comment: @petr0 This is working for me when the ask-pass password is for a different user than the key (i.e. when you switch remote user after disabling passworded ssh).  Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the `PreferredAuthentications` option, setting it to `publickey,password`. The default includes these in this order, along with other options, so ansible is presumably setting this. Adding it via `-o` or the client `ssh_config` may prevent this.

You may be able to use a wrapper script. For example, with this in `key_or_password.sh` and a `pass.sh` that gives the password, running `bash key_or_password.sh root@host` will try a publickey followed by a non-interactive password login.

```
export DISPLAY=dummy:0
export SSH_ASKPASS=$PWD/pass.sh
exec setsid ssh -v -o 'PreferredAuthentications publickey,password' "$@"
```

The log indicates which method succeeded with, e.g.

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I do if `ansible_user` is different for the 'first run' of the playbook (for example if you only have a `root` user and you're going to set up a new user with an SSH key):

- Store the password in `ansible_pass` as you would if you were using password logins (remember to use Vault) this should be the password of the user you're using for the 'first run' of the playbook.
- Set `ansible_user` to the username of the user you wish to use after the first run when you have users set up correctly on the server.
- Set a variable of `ansible_user_first_run` to the user you're going to use for the 'first run' of the playbook, for example `root`.
- Use a local command to attempt to connect to the server with the correct SSH key, using `ignore_errors` and `changed_when: False`
- If that fails, update `ansible_user` to the value of `ansible_user_first_run`

Here's the code:

```
---
- name: Check if connection is possible
  command: ssh -o User={{ ansible_user }} -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes {{ inventory_hostname }} echo "Worked"
  register: result
  connection: local
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: False
- name: If no connection, change user_name
  connection: local
  set_fact:
    ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user_first_run }}"
  when: result|failed
```

Note: It's worth setting up `transport = ssh` as paramiko can unexpectedly fail to login to the server in some configurations (e.g. when the server is set up not to accept passwords, and you're trying first with a key then a password... weird!) Also ssh transport is faster, so it's worth it anyway.

Further note: If you're using this method, you need to specify `gather_facts: false` in your playbook definition file so that the setup / fact gathering tasks aren't run automatically before you get to the stage of testing passwords. If you need any of the ansible facts, you will need to explicitly call `setup` in your role before accessing any of the data normally available in such places as `ansible_devices`, etc. One good way of doing this is to call `setup` with a `when` clause that checks to see if the fact you are using is empty or not before you call it in your role.

Comment: Your solution is good but you must add a `gather_facts: no` to stop ansible trying to connect when launching the playbook :)

Comment: You are correct. I have gather_facts set to off for all my playbooks so that I have to call 'setup' explicitly. I forgot to mention this in the answer, I will update it now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `--ask-pass` when running ansible-playbook.

For other tasks you asked, it is achievable by various means, eg, copy module.
Disabling root login also can be done eg. by templating `sshd_conf` or inserting line in conf file.

Comment: --ask-pass (which is the same as -k) is what I'm doing and I wrote about it in the comment above

Answer (score 3):

I've recently implemented a variant of the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/755006/144264) given above by [Tom Bull](https://serverfault.com/users/156675/tom-bull)  which works for multiple hosts, sequentially checking for access and prompting for credentials if needed, then running tasks to finish setup (e.g. adding authorised keys, or setting up a user for Ansible):

**`playbook.yaml`**:

```
# Checking access to hosts must run sequentially
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: check-access.yaml

# Subsequent tasks can run in parallel as usual 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: setup-tasks.yaml
```

**`check-access.yaml`**:

```
- name: check ansible user exists
  command: ssh -o User={{ ansible_user }} -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes {{ ansible_host }} echo "Worked"
  register: remote
  connection: local
  ignore_errors: yes
  become: false
  changed_when: False

- name: collect credentials
  block:
    - name: collect username
      pause:
        prompt: "Username for {{ inventory_hostname }} ({{ ansible_host }})"
        echo: yes
      register: username_result

    - name: collect password
      pause:
        prompt: "Password for {{ username_result.user_input }}"
        echo: no
      register: password_result

    - name: update ansible credentials
      set_fact:
        ansible_user: "{{ username_result.user_input }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ password_result.user_input }}"
        ansible_become_password: "{{ password_result.user_input }}"
  when: remote.failed
```

`setup-tasks.yaml` will then be run on all hosts, and can include whatever tasks are needed to ensure that the initial access check will succeed when `playbook.yaml` is next run.

Whilst keeping the `check-access.yaml` tasks in a separate file does make the main playbook easier to read, it may be possible to bring them into the main playbook -  however I have not tried this so cannot be certain that they will run in the correct order.

Note that these tasks **cannot** be placed into a role, as `prompt` only works within tasks